# How to use Jquery to change the third select box when the first select box is changed or triggered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

Hi i would like to know how to use jQuery to change the third select box (#school) when ever the first select box on change event is triggered. 
When select box 1 is selected, select box should change and select box three should also automatically change to reflect the options that correspond to what is in select box two.

```js
$("#certificate").change(function() {
  if ($(this).data('options') == undefined) {
    $(this).data('options', $('#program option').clone());
  }
  var id = $(this).val();
  var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[class=' + id + ']');
  $('#program').html(options).show();
});

$("#program").change(function() {
  if ($(this).data('options') == undefined) {
    $(this).data('options', $('#school option').clone());
  }
  var id = $(this).val();
  var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[class=' + id + ']');
  $('#school').html(options).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="select1" id="certificate">
    <option value="">Select Country</option>
    <option value="india">India</option>
    <option value="america">America</option>
</select>


<select name="select2" id="program" >
    <option value="">Select State</option>
    <option class="india" value="orissa">Orissa</option>
    <option class="india" value="telangan">Telangan</option>
    <option class="america" value="america">USA</option>
    <option class="america" value="america">California</option>
</select>

<select name="select3" id="school" >
    <option value="">Select city</option>
    <option class="orissa">Nal</option>
    <option class="orissa">Mir</option>
    <option class="telangan">Hyd</option>
    <option class="telangan">Vija</option>
    <option class="america">KRK</option>
    <option class="america">MRK</option>
</select>
```

Comment: If `india` is selected in dropbox, `select3` should be visible, when `america` - `select2`?

Comment: @Kinduser Okay i can take out the style="display: none;. But it still does not work

Comment: You didn't actually answer on my question. Is my way of thinking right? Is that what do you expect?

Comment: @Kinduser if india is selected Orissa should automatically be selected on the select2 and then Nal be selected on select3